# Historical data of financial funds

Tags: import, curated-data, finance

I would like to obtain the historical data of some funds, of which I know the ISIN code. Is there any way to do this with mathematica?

For example, this fund here:
https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s=IE00B1Z6D669:EUR

Comment: How far back do you want to go?

Comment: I would need only 2-3 years. Unfortunately all the markets I invest in are not covered by Financialdata, so I need to import from external source.

Comment: If you have an external source in mind with a documented API, there are examples on the site of taking advantage of those. But finding the source is not really a Mathematica question yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateListPlot[FinancialData["TSLA", "Jan. 1, 2020"]]
```

Comment: Would this work with the ISIN code (eg for Tesla stock, US88160R1014) rather than the ticker symbol (TSLA)?

Comment: I've never used ISIN... sorry.

Comment: It does not work with financialdata, this is the point of my question. FInancialdata does not retreive funds from ISIN.